# Is there an ASP.NET event that occurs after postback, but before the page is destroyed/recreated?

Tags: asp.net, events, forms, post, event-handling

My ASP.NET form contains a collection of dynamically-created radiobuttons that are created and configured in the Page_Load event handler.

Normally, I process postback data in the Page_Load handler, using the condition:

```
if (IsPostBack)
```

However, since the controls that I need to access are created IN the Page_Load handler, the postback data from the previous rendering of the page is lost. To better illustrate the problem, here is an outline of the events as they occur:
`1-Page_Load is invoked for the first time`
`2-An unknown number of radiobuttons are created dynamically`
`3-The radiobuttons are configured, based on information present on the server`
`4-The radiobuttons are added to the page's content`
`5-The user selects an option, and clicks the submit button`
`6-The Page_Load handler is invoked for the second time`
`7-The radio-buttons are added dynamically, exactly as before`
`8-The radio-button that the user checked is seemingly non-existant for processing`

It seems like I need to be processing different parts of this in different event handlers. Is there an event that occurs after postback, but while the original radiobuttons are still accessible?

Comment: Override OnInit() and create your RadioButtonList there.  Then, they'll be accessible throughout postbacks.

Comment: Can you build your control structure in **init** instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the "Init" events...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx